# How to compare the value of sqlite table to the json tag value in android

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I want to compare the value of the id in `sqlite` to the value of `TAG_ID` coming from the json webservice.I just stuck up to do this..

What I have tried so far is

```
class LoadAll extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
    {

            protected String doInBackground(String... args) 
            {
                Log.i("url ",url_all_products);

                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET",params);
                    Log.w("All book: ", json.toString());
                    Log.i(url_all_products, url_all_products);                     
                    try 
                    {
                        System.err.println("json array "+json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS));
                        bookProduct = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    } 
                    catch (JSONException e) 
                    {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                    } 
                    if(data_exist!=bookProduct.length()){
                        Log.i("in update","m here");
                         Cursor cursors = getRawEvents("select id from bcuk_book");

                             try{

                             for (int i = 0; i < bookProduct.length(); i++) {
                                 JSONObject c = bookProduct.getJSONObject(i);

                                 String Bid = c.getString(TAG_ID);

                                 ArrayList<String> mapId = new ArrayList<String>();

                                    mapId.add(TAG_ID);

                                    Log.e(Bid,Bid);

                                    while(cursors.moveToNext())
                                    {
                                     System.err.println("update coded STEON"+cursors.getString(0));
                                     Log.e(Bid,c.getString(TAG_ID));

                                    }
                             }

                         }
                             catch(JSONException e){
                                 e.printStackTrace();
                             }
                    }
                    else{
                        Log.i("Done good","m here");
                    }
                    return null;               
            }
```

The reason behind

```
    if(data_exist!=bookProduct.length()){
```

this statement is the variable `data_exist=cursor.getCount();`

and the `bookProduct.length` is the length of the jsonarray I want to compare them if the length is not same then I want to update the new values into the sqlite.could any one suggest me the approach to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the length is not same then I want to update the new values into
>   the sqlite.

Not a good way to update databases.
Suppose that there is some changes in the server database fields. Same count but the contents is different.
This is the way I do:

```
 String sql = "select * from " + DB_TABLE + " where " + TAG_ID + "='" + id + "'";
 Cursor c = database.rawQuery(sql, null);
 c.moveToFirst();
 if( c.getCount() > 0){ // already in the database
      // update entry with TAG_ID = id
  }
  else{ // new entry
      // add new entry
  }
```